# egrep: find lines with no characters

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a text file and I need to search that file and figure how many blank lines are in the file. A blank line is a line with no characters.

I must use egrep.

Comment: I've been out of school almost 10 years buddy. Look at my question history before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: "Homework" was a question, not a conclusion. "I *must* use `egrep`" is a strange restriction. I believe my questions are still valid.

Comment: Is it a prerequisite here on SO that when you post a question you must list every solution that you've tried? Why does it matter to you that I must use egrep? Have you considered that I might be a guy who's taking some spare time on a Saturday afternoon to broaden his knowledge about new things?

Comment: An unqualified *I must use `egrep`* sounds a lot like a homework problem which is something we try to shy away from.  We aren't mind readers, so you could have done a better job qualifying it.

Comment: Understood. I recommend reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to get some tips on how to write questions that get good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[aman@localhost ~]$  cat >try

```
    sldjjsd


    dkfjkjdf


    dfkjdf
```

[aman@localhost ~]$ `egrep '^$' try|wc -l`

**`4`**

Comment: Arrrgh. I feel stupid for not figuring that out. I'm learning regular expressions using egrep on my own and I was trying '^[^.]$' as my regex string. Thanks for the answer without an attitude. It's nice when people are civil.

Comment: yes,regexps can really test one's patience.Thanks for the kind words though :)

Comment: No need for `wc`. Try `egrep -c '^$'` @JohnConnor: You were close with ` '^[^.]$'`, but this would look for an impossible line (one character that is not "anything").

Answer (score 3):

**This will do.**

```
egrep '^$' blankfile -c
```

---

Another way, without egrep.

```
echo $(($(cat blank | wc -l)-$(cat blank | tr -s "\n"  | wc -l)))
```

Comment: needless io redirect. `wc -l blank` will do the same work with one pipe less

Comment: @knittl `wc -l blank` will output something like this, `15 blank`

Comment: Wow! How overly complicated is *that*!?

Comment: @Johnsyweb The 2nd one? I dont know any better.

Comment: The (edited) first one is perfect. The second one has two [UUOC](http://uuoc.com/)s and parses the input file twice.